# changes made to firebase currentUser is not reflected until full reload of the application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I want to update displayName of the current user and display it on screen.

```
firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((response) => {response.user.updateProfile({displayName: 'John Doe'}),response.user.reload()})
        .catch(error => Alert.alert('', error.message));
console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName);
```

using this code it is returning null on first but when I reload the app it is returning 'John Doe' how can i do it without reloading app.

Comment: Don't repost the same question multiple times please. Instead, add any clarifications to the question you originally posted. There's a handy edit link right under it, that allows you to do so. When you edit your question, it become eligible for reopening.

Answer (score 1):

Call [reload()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reload) on the user object after updating the profile.  Note that it returns a promise to indicate when that's done.