# Firebase displayName is only shown after Re-login not at the first login

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I have 2 methods. One that creates user called `signUp` and other that adds display name to user profile called `updatesUser`. During the signUp process, I am calling updateUser method as well.
Once registration is successful, the user is sent to HomeScreen.

However, on signUp completion when user is at HomeScreen, the display name is shown as "null". But then it works when the same user logs out and comes back in.

User object and refs are defined in parent class of these methods:

```
class FirebaseController extends GetxController {
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Rx<User> _firebaseUser = Rx<User>();
  String get user => _firebaseUser.value?.email;
  String get userid => _firebaseUser.value?.uid;
  String get displayName => _firebaseUser.value?.displayName;



void signUp(String username, String email, String password) async {
    CollectionReference dbref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users");

    await _auth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
        .then((value) {
      dbref
          .doc(userid)
          .set({
            "username": username,
            "email": email,
            "password": password,
            "uid": userid,
           })
          .then((value) => updateUser(username: username))
          .then((value) => Get.offAll(HomeScreen()));
    }).catchError(
      (onError) =>
          Get.snackbar("Error while creating account ", onError.message),
    );
  }
```

This is my updateUser method that is called during "signUp"

```
void updateUser({username}) async {
    await _auth.currentUser
        .updateProfile(displayName: username)
        .then((value) => _firebaseUser.value.reload())
        .then((value) => Get.snackbar("User Created", "User has been created"))
        .catchError((onError) =>
            Get.snackbar("Error while Updating DisplayName ", onError.message));
  }
```

**What am I doing Wrong?!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about what you're doing wrong.  It's about what you're not doing at all.

Updating the user profile does not update the User object for the currently signed in user.  If you want to see changes to the new profile, you have to use [reload()](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/reload.html) on that user object.

See also:

- [What use case has the reload() function of a FirebaseUser in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51709733/what-use-case-has-the-reload-function-of-a-firebaseuser-in-flutter)
- [changes made to firebase currentUser is not reflected until full reload of the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61416247/changes-made-to-firebase-currentuser-is-not-reflected-until-full-reload-of-the-a)

Comment: I tried reloading user in both methods but it's still the same.
Added following to my updateUser method. My user object is defined in a Auth class

`Rx<User> _firebaseUser = Rx<User>();
  String get displayName => _firebaseUser.value?.displayName;`

`.then((value) => _firebaseUser.value.reload())`

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that doesn't work the way you expect.  Code in comments is exceptionally difficult to read.  Be sure that you are correctly accessing the currentUser object again after the call to `reload()` **fully completes** - if you're not, that's a different issue.

Comment: Question has been updated. Now it shows where & how the user object is created and also shows that in userUpdate method the user object is also reloaded after updating displayname.

Comment: reload() returns a Future - you're not taking that into account by accessing currentUser only after the Future shows that it's complete.